# Google AdSense sometimes shows earning without click?

Tags: google-adsense

Google AdSense sometimes shows earning without any click. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: I have a same problem, earnings from my blog are not included by clicks even though it reached 10% CTR average, all the earnings come from CPM. I don't know why clicks are not included in the report!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably [Google Adsense CPM](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=18196)

Comment: oh, so CPM ads are not meant for click, only display is sufficient to give money to publisher?

Comment: sorry for cross post, i deleted that post in SO

Comment: Yes. Basically if enough impressions are made the publisher gets paid. e.g. 1,000 impressions = 1¢. It's not a lot of money but it does add up if you have a very high traffic web site. That's why keeping users on your website is so important.